# Basic Git branching

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch, msysgit

I am fairly new with Git and using Git on my windows machine through the command prompt.
Currently I only have got one master branch and I want to create a new branch (current). I'm a bit confused with some of the commands.

Can someone give me some instructions to follow? I don't find git references very useful. I am not new to source control, just new to Git. Thanks.

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book this is an excellent resource

Comment: or read gitready.com, which is a really good tutorial site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book).

To make a branch in the same place as you are in history:

```
git branch branch_name
```

to switch to that branch use

```
git checkout branch_name
```

you can do both of those at the same time with:

```
git checkout -b branch_name
```

to keep alternating between the last 2 branches use

```
git checkout -
```

(this is the similar to the behaviour of `cd -`)

Once you get better with the syntax of git, use a good branching strategy and stick with it. I use [Branch per Feature](http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/).

Answer (score 0):

This book will give you good introduction. It explains the commands in very detail and some with graphs to let you know the work process of git.
http://git-scm.com/book
You can give create a branch with command like this:

```
git checkout -b branch_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the git pro book - it's not a long read, and its free. It will teach you all the important concepts and would be much better than just giving you the branching syntax.

http://www.git-scm.com/book

However, to branch try:

```
git checkout -b <name>
```

Which will create a new branch and switch to it.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial is the best interactive tutorial available online if you would like to clear your concepts of git branching.

http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/index.html?demo

Answer (score -1):

to create a branch

`$ git checkout -b your_branch`

to add to staging area and commit changes - all(shortcut)

`$ git commit -a -m "your message"`

to push to hithub(only if you already have a repo)

`$ git push origin your_branch`

Comment: the question is about branches - not committing or pushing. Please keep answers on topic.